# Node.js: using mongodb stream with pause and resume sometimes causes 100% CPU utilization

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a process which fetches data from mongodb and creates a stream for the same. I am fetching records from DB, hitting some API and then storing the results back to DB. Since database fetch is much faster than the API response, I am pausing and resuming the stream after every 40 records. However, after a while the process stops in the middle without any error. When I see the logs, everything seems fine but not sure why the process does not proceed further. I have tried setting timeout of 1 second before resume but no luck so far. Also, the issue is sporadic, sometimes it works perfectly fine but many times it just pauses in the middle. Is there any better recommended way of handling this type of scenario

```
var productStream = db.product.find(query).stream();
```

Then I process each product like this

```
productStream.on('data', function (product) {

    //do some processing

})
```

I am maintaining two variables for tracking the count of records in stream and count of processed records. I pause the stream when count reaches 40

```
if (count == 40) {
  console.log(totalCount, Date());
  productStream.pause();
}
```

During this processing I keep on pausing and resuming the stream. Here is the function that I use for calling resume

```
function checkResumeStream() {
  if (count == 40 && processed_count >= count) {
    count = 0;
    processed_count = 0;
    productStream.resume();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Now when I checked the logs carefully and also the top command, I can see that logs almost come to a halt everytime the processed_count reaches 38 (it resumes when it reaches 40). Also, when I check the result of top command, I can see that during that point CPU usage increases to 100% for mongod. I have mongodb settings to log each query slower than 100ms in db.system.profile but there are no queries being logged. So I dont understand where mongod is using up all the CPU ?

Comment: Try listen `productStream.on('finish', function() { //log something })` , and see if it enters here.

Comment: Already listening on the 'end' event and its not going there.           `productStream.on('end', function () {
            console.log("CLOSED!!!")
            resolve()
          });`

Comment: not `end`, but `finish`

Comment: Tried that too... It just pauses after a while.

Comment: When the count nearly reaches the point when I need to resume the stream, top command shows mongod CPU utilization at 100%. Otherwise it remains as low as 2% thorughout. Everytime before resume it shoots up

Comment: Maybe there are less than 40 records in the last fetching, and you are not processing this case.

Comment: @Edgar : In that case... shouldn't the end or finish callback be called ?....while mandeep_m91 says that it just pauses.

Comment: @Edgar : there are much more records in the db. However we are trying out with {timeout: false} in the stream to see if it works

Comment: @mandeep_m91 I've written not about the records in db, but about the records in the last fetching.

Comment: even then the number of records is not a problem because when I check the logs, it shows that stream was paused after fetching 40 records and then 40 records were processed and the code reaches the place where it calls the resume() function